# Mollom and Spamicide are not slowing down spam registrations

Tags: 6, security, advertising

I have a drupal 6 site. I'm using both Mollom and Spamicide.

Mollom is doing a great job at stopping spam comments but spambots are registering at an extremely high rate over 6 per minute.

Registration uses a captcha from Mollom and Spamicide but they seem to be going right through both. Spamicide slowed them down for about half a day but now that seems to be doing nothing.

Additionally, about 80% of the spambot accounts are validating their accounts through email - they create tons hotmail accounts with generic names.

Any ideas or recommendations on stemming the tide?

I've been trying to find a way of automatically blocking IPs that are throwing a high number of registrations or other suspect activity.

Comment: You could also try reCAPTCHA on the user/register form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still try to use CloudFlare service, coupling with Mollom it's very effective.

Also, I'm not sure that they (bots I mean) are creating account e-mail to validate their account. The problem with Drupal 6, its has an algorithm to create the validation link that it's easier to reproduce (much harder with Drupal 7 as its has a secret key when you install).

Well, if with CloudFlare it doesn't slow down your spam problem, you can either change the validation algorithm or upgrade to Drupal 7.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and heads up about the drupal 6 issue. Still working on tuning but this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Spammers seem to be working at a faster rate then we can block them for the most part, but there's still some things I find helpful in slowing them down.

I find using image captcha vs regular captcha works way better. If you're finding that that you're getting hit from the same IP address, google it and find out if it's a known spammer. If it is, block it.

Since not filling in the field verifies you're human with Spamicide, calling the field a name that spambots normally fill in are more likely to fail validation.  Spambots won't fill in a field called "what's my mom's name?", but likely will fill out "city" or "name." Assuming you don't need those fields anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in order to know the ip address of a user and multiple accounts he created, you can use this module https://drupal.org/project/ip

Comment: Welcome to SE Read How do I write a good answer to a question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656

Answer (score 0):

For preventing spam login creation I suggest you ask simple GK questions like "largest bank in your country", "largest river" etc.

For comments I suggest you block http:// or https:// in comments. Plenty of spam( I guess at least 25%) will be filtered.

Don't block IP's. For example in India plenty of IP's are dynamic. I guest IP's of most of wireless internet directly from provider will be dynamic.